# Prove that if F and G are nonempty families of sets, then $\bigcup \mathcal F \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal G$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am sorry, I couldn't write the whole statement in the title, because it is too long. Here is the full statement:

> Suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are nonempty families of sets, and every element of $\mathcal F$ is a subset of every element of $\mathcal G$. Prove that $\bigcup \mathcal F \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal G$

My attempt:

Let $x \in \mathcal \bigcup F$.

Since $x \in \bigcup \mathcal F$, there is at least one set, call it $A$, such that $x \in A$ and $A \in \mathcal F$. "Every element of $\mathcal F$ is a subset of every element of $\mathcal G$" means that that $\forall M \in \mathcal G (A\subseteq M)$. And since $x \in A$, it follows that $\forall M \in \mathcal G (x \in M)$. By definition of $\bigcap G$, we conclude that $x \in \bigcap G$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we can also conclude that $\forall x(x \in \bigcup \mathcal F \implies x \in \bigcap \mathcal G)$, therefore $\bigcup \mathcal F \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal G.$ $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: The first part is bad. Why are you saying "if"???? You just said $x$ is in the union.

Comment: Rest is correct, although I don't like "because .... then"

Comment: @mathworker21 If you are referring to the "If $x \in \bigcup \mathcal F$", what I meant to say was "Since we've just supposed that $x \in \bigcup \mathcal F$", I just condensed it.

Comment: I corrected "because ... then"

Comment: "if" means something different than "since we've just supposed that". also, "since ... then" I also think is wrong. In any event, the solution is mathematically correct, so good job

Comment: If "since .... then" is wrong, then what would be the correct way?

Comment: Which sounds correct to you? "Since I wasn't hungry, I decided to skip lunch". "Since I wasn't hungry, then I decided to skip lunch"

Comment: Yeah, in the example that you provided, "since ... then" indeed sounds weird. So if I get you correctly, instead of "since .... , then ....." I should just write "since.... , .....". Right?

Comment: I think in any example it would sound weird. And yes, that's correct.

Comment: I made corrections.

Comment: Perfect!,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

If A in F, then for all B in G, A subset B.
Thus for all A in F, A subset $\cap$G.
Consequently $\cup$F subset $\cap$G.